# How can I embed an S3 hosted PDF? instead of having it download automatically in the browser?

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3

My server is node.js but I am sending out a URL to the PDF hosted on S3. Using Chrome, the PDF downloads automatically even when embedded in a div or iframe. How can I force it to be embedded?

A link to one PDF in my S3 bucket:
http://ws902.s3.amazonaws.com/pdf_1367897334399.pdf

-

Code I'm using that works fine when it's a local PDF...

```
<iframe src="myfile.pdf" width="100%" style="height:20em"></iframe>
```

or

```
<div id="pdf"><object data="myfile.pdf" type="application/pdf"></object></div>
```

Comment: I don't think this is something you get to control.  The browser is what controls what happens when you click on a particular link

Answer (score 10):

The solution was to send file headers with the file to S3. S3 serves the files with the same mime type as it was uploaded. By default this is octet, so I changed it to application/pdf.

Using node.js and knox:

```
headers: { 'x-amz-acl': 'public-read','Content-Type': 'application/pdf' }
```

Answer (score -3):

To elaborate on Alex D's answer regarding node.js and uploading a public pdf to s3 using headers:

[image: Node.js working application uploading public pdf to s3]